# what is OCaml's "ground coercion"?

Tags: types, ocaml

OCaml sometimes gives a warning "this ground coercion is not principal".  I think I understand the "not principal" part (the type inference gives at least two possible types, neither of which is a subtype of the other), but I don't know what the "ground coercion" is.

I suspect the answer must involve some amount of abstract type theory, but I would much appreciate concrete examples also.

Comment: Well, this message is not very legible and there are proposals to be changed since 2012. No things have been made yet by technical difficulties on printing types, as much as it requires a specific formatter.

Answer (score 10):

> The answer below is from [Jeremy Yallop](https://github.com/yallop). I cite it from the OCaml mailing list, because I failed to find an online link to the posting.

[tl;dr: the message means "The type of the expression is not known.
Add type annotations for the variables in the expression."]

Background: a private type abbreviation is defined by a type alias
definition with the word 'private'.  For example, the following
definition

```
type t = private int
```

makes t a kind of half alias for int: you can convert from type t to
int, but you can't convert from int to t.  Coercions are performed
with the ':>' operator, so you can write things like this

```
let f (x : t) = (x :>  int)
```

to convert from the private type t to the abbreviated type int.

Now, in order to check whether the following coercion is valid

```
(x :> int)
```

the compiler needs to know the type of x.  There might be several
candidates: for example, with the private type abbreviation above in
scope, the coercion is valid if x has type t, but do-nothing coercions
are also allowed, so int is another reasonable possibility.  How can
the compiler choose between these alternatives to find the type of x?
In the definition of f above choosing is easy: x is a function
argument with an annotation, so the compiler just uses that
annotation.  Here's a slightly trickier case:

```
let g (y : t) = ()

let h x = (g x, (x :> int))
```

What's the type of x here?  The compiler's inference algorithm checks
the elements of a pair from left to right, so here's what happens:

1. Initially, when type checking for h starts, the type of x is unknown
2. The subexpression g x is checked, assigning x the type t, i.e.
   the type of g's argument
3. The coercion (x :> int) is checked, and determined to be correct
   since t can be coerced to int.

However, if the inference algorithm instead checked the elements of a
pair from right to left we'd have the following sequence of steps:

Initially, when type checking for h starts, the type of x is unknown
  (2) The coercion (x :> int) is checked, and the compiler guesses the
type of x.  In the absence of other information it guesses int.
  (3) The subexpression g x is checked and rejected, because x has
type int, not t.

Indeed, if we exchange the elements of the pair to simulate this
second behaviour

```
let h2 x = ((x :> int), g x)
```

then the coercion is rejected:

```
let h x = ((x :> int), g x);;
                         ^
Error: This expression has type int but an expression was expected of type t
```

Since it's better for programs not to depend on the particular order
used by the inference algorithm, the compiler emits a warning.  You
can address the warning by annotating the binding for x:

```
let h (x : t) = (g x, (x :> int))
```

Comment: ftr https://inbox.ocaml.org/caml-list/CAAxsn=EAaNQ3DszD4bsHt4=A0vmshm28W3omtfk685+_S0i25w@mail.gmail.com/